# How to add check in Apache so that any requests with query parameters longer than 800 characters are stripped out

Tags: apache, dispatcher

I have a requirement that if request with query parameter is longer than 800 than stripped out. I have to do in apache.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
We can achieve this by

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .{800}
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=414,L]